# Change Visited Link

Tags: php, html

I have this code:

```
<div class="menuList">
    <li><a href="/arena/"><img src="/images/icon/arena.png" alt="">Arena<span class="green"> (+)</span></a>
    </li>

</div>
```

And i want to remove `<span class="green"> (+)</span>` after users click that link.
Anyone can help me (php code)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned, PHP is not the ideal language to do this in. But, if you need to use PHP, here is how you could do it.

Set a session variable on the /arena/ page, like this;

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSSION['visited'] = 1;
?>
```

Then, use PHP to check for the session variable in your HTML code like this:

```
<div class="menuList">
<li><a href="/arena/"><img src="/images/icon/arena.png" alt="">Arena
<?PHP
If(isset($_SESSION['visited'])){
  echo '<span class="green"> (+)</span>';
}
?>
</a>
</li>

</div>
```

You will need to add session_start() to the top of the page wherever you are accessing session variables, before you output anything to the page (e.g. DOCTYPE declaration.)

Comment: What error is it throwing? What page is this HTML code on? Is the link sending you to a new page, or the same one? Are you testing locally, or on your web host? Also, it would help to see more of your source code. Otherwise, I can't really give you more than this.

Comment: arena -> to arena page. when i visited arena page, span (+) not appears.

Comment: the link to new page "arena"

Comment: So the menuList div is on the arenapage.php, and the link sends you to arena.php? I need more info about what page contains the source code you posted, what the file relation is with the page you are linking to, and how you want the code to work.

Answer (score 1):

in Jquery you may do this like

```
<script>
$(function(){
     $('.menuList').find('a').click(function(){
        $(this).children('.green').remove();    
      });
 });  
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by adding this javascript to your page:

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
  var a = document.querySelector('.menuList a');
  a.onclick = function() {
    var span = a.querySelector('.green');
    a.removeChild(span);
  }
}
</script>
```

OR if you're using jQuery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.menuList').find('a').click(function(){
    $(this).find('.green').remove(); 
  }); 
});
</script>
```